# Air HTML Component and HTML_RENDER event

Tags: flex4, air, mxml

We are currently using the mx:HTML component to render complex HTML pages (which was pretty disturbing..:)). For some reasons, we need, when the HTML is rendered, to capture an image of the displayed page. So i use the following code to do this :

on initialization :

```
frameHtml.addEventListener(Event.HTML_RENDER, cacheFrameHTML);
```

and the cacheFrameHTML function :

```
private function cacheFrameHTML(event:*):void {
...
cacheImage.source = new Bitmap( ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData(frameHtml));
...
}
```

For some unknown reason, the result image is sometime completly blank. It seems that there is a short delay between HTML_RENDER event and effective rendering of the HTML component. I tried to delay the image capture with a timer which seems to work, but that is not pretty clean.

So my question is : 
- is there anyone who know a trick to only trigger the capture when the HTML frame is effectivly displayed?
- at least, is there anyway to test if the result BitmapData is blank or have only white pixels?:b

Thanks a lot

Antoine

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the callLater method?

> The callLater() method queues an operation to be performed for the next screen refresh, rather than in the current update

```
private function cacheFrameHTML(event:*):void {
...
callLater(saveImage);
...
}

private function saveImage():void
{
cacheImage.source = new Bitmap( ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData(frameHtml));
}
```

Comment: Yes, but i still get a blank image.